# Is it possible to Validate Digital Signature and create new document, so that Adobe reader or Foxit reader should not validate the same at startup

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I wanted to silently print the documents from C# iTextSharp (using Foxit reader process ) after digitally signing the document.
Once the document is printed the Yellow color question mark is affixed in the signature part,

When i open the document in Foxit reader and print the same, then green check mark is visible ( Since the Foxit reader will validate the signature on startup )

So overall i need to save the PDF with validated signature using C# and iTextSharp, so that the green check mark should come by default and same should be visible in silent print ( Without needed to open the file first using Foxit/Adobe reader ).

I Tried setting Acro6Layers as true, but in that case neither green check mark will be shown, nor the question mark,

I tried to silently print the document using Adobe Reader and it works fine ( Since the Adobe reader window will be popped up and do the signing process even in the silent print mode, but in case of Foxit reader no such window will be opened during the silent print )

```
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        appearance.Reason = reason;
        appearance.Location = location;
        appearance.Acro6Layers = false;            
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 730, 144, 790), 1, "sig");         
        // Creating the signature
        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm);

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
```

Expected result: Green check mark should be affixed during the silent print using Foxit reader. 
Actual result:  Yellow question mark is affixing in silent print

Comment: Simply sign with a green sign as background image of the signature and Acro6Layers as true; this way it will always be there. Changing the in-document appearance of signatures is a deprecated Adobe "feature" not (or probably differently) supported by other pdf viewers.

Comment: If we turn Acro6layers to true and set greencheck as background image then the text saying "Signature is valid" also won't appear, so it might not be acceptable

Comment: Which *text saying "Signature is valid"*? Text on the page or text in the signature panel or dialogs? If on the page, then you can add that to the signature appearance, too. If in a panel or dialog, then that is not relevant for printing and, furthermore, a question of actual signature validity.

Comment: I mean the text Signature Valid on : [link](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fsigndesk.com%2Fin%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F09%2FAfter-Validation.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fsigndesk.com%2Fin%2Fesign%2Fhow-to-validate-esign&docid=wQ52erFA2mPdVM&tbnid=zUwulzEH4Z0yQM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjMy-X3it7iAhUihuYKHdT7AMEQMwhVKAIwAg..i&w=1022&h=502&client=firefox-b-e&bih=943&biw=1920&q=digital%20signature%20green%20check%20mark%20graphic&ved=0ahUKEwjMy-X3it7iAhUihuYKHdT7AMEQMwhVKAIwAg&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comment: Obviously you can add that to the appearance, too, if you want to see it.